# python selenium element not interactable when bot tries to click agreement button

Tags: python, html, selenium

```
<input id="agreement-input-mobile" class="agreement-input" type="checkbox" name="agreement" aria-describedby="agreement-content">
```

im trying to automate a certain task but it needs to click an agreement button but every time I try to select it I get this error

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.67)
```

here's what my line of code looks like

```
driver.find_element_by_name('agreement').click()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of `.click()` method, you can try another way like this:

1. Using **`ActionChains`**:

   ```
   #following import
   from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


   element = driver.find_element_by_id('agreement-input-mobile')
   action = ActionChains(driver)
   action.move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
   ```
2. Using `.execute_script`:

   ```
   element = driver.find_element_by_id('agreement-input-mobile')
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
   ```

Comment: yea that's what literally worked I figured it out like 30 mins ago thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend to find elements by name. Use ID or xpath. So change `driver.find_element_by_name('agreement').click()` to `driver.find_element_by_id('agreement-input-mobile').click()`

Comment: Are you sure the button is visible? Ex. you don't have to scroll down to press the button or the button is disabled? Are you filling in all the required fields before you press agree?